# JavaScript Event Listeners in Function vs Inline?

Tags: drag-and-drop, dom-events, draggable, addeventlistener, event-listener

Here's the scenerio...

I have elements on page that are drag enabled using the following tag:

```
draggable="true"
```

At the bottom of the page I've initiated an "dragstart" event listener with a call back function like so:

```
draggable.addEventListener('dragstart', on_dragStart, false);
```

I drag a few items over to the drop area which works fine, but when I try to rearrange the elements within the drop area I'm not able to drag the elements around even though the entire html element node was copied over. I'm getting the following error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cloneNode' of null".

I read somewhere (which not I can't find) awhile ago that the event listener bind is destroyed when the element is copied over to the drop area. Did I recall this correctly?

When I add the event listener within the element like so:

```
ondragstart="on_dragStart(event)"
```

It works fine with no errors. Can someone quickly please explain why this is true? Or at least point me in the right direction. I want to make sure I'm understanding event listeners correctly without making any assumptions.